# Infinitely many primes of the form $6n - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove there are infinitely many primes of the form $6n - 1$ with the following: (i) Prove that the product of two numbers of the form $6n + 1$ is also of that form. That is, show that $(6j + 1)(6k + 1) = 6m + 1$, for some choice of $m$. (ii) Show that every prime $p$ greater than $3$ is necessarily of the form $6n + 1$ or $6n − 1$.

Comment: We will also need a variant of a trick you have seen. To show there is a prime of that form $\gt n$, look at $6n!-1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am required to use this much to write a proof. I am very new to this.

Comment: The title of the post is not correct usage for the occasion.  In mathematical terminology, "infinite primes" means "primes, each one of which is infinite".  It doesn't mean "infinitely many primes".  So if there were six primes, each infinite, then there would be infinite primes, but not infinitely many primes.

Comment: @Rebecca: I was mentioning an additional item, which you need for the proof there are infinitely many primes of the required form, in addition to (i) (and (ii), but (ii) is not really needed).

Comment: I have a feeling this question has been asked on here before. I'll vote to close for it being a duplicate, but to close it for being off-topic is ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

**(i) $(6m+1)\times(6n+1) = 36mn + 6m + 6n + 1 = 6(6mn + m + n) + 1$**

**(ii)  To prove all primes are of the form $6n + 1$ or $6n - 1$, consider:**

- $6x+0 = 6x$
- $6x+2 = 2(3x+1)$
- $6x+3 = 3(2x+1)$
- $6x+4 = 2(3x+2)$
- $6x+5 = 6(x+1) - 1$

**(iii) To prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $6n-1$ consider:**

$(6m+1)\times(6n-1) = 36mn - 6m + 6n - 1 = 6(6mn -m +n) - 1$

$(6m-1)\times(6n-1) = 36mn - 6m - 6n + 1 = 6(6mn - m - n) + 1$

So, if we only consider numbers that are a product of primes $p > 3$, their product will always be $6x+1$ or $6x-1$

Assume $y$ is the greatest prime of the form $6x-1$

Let $v = $ product of all primes $p$ where $3 < p \le y$ so that $v$ is of the form $6x-1$ or $6x+1$

if $v$ is of the form $6x-1$, then $v+6$ is of the form $6(x+1)-1$ and is not divisible by any prime $\le y$.  If it is not prime, then it must be divisible by at least one prime of the form $6x-1$.  Otherwise, its form would be $6x+1$

if $v$ is of the form $6x+1$, then $v-2$ is of the form $6x+1-2 = 6x-1$ and is not divisible by any prime $\le y$.  If it is not prime, then it must be divisible by at least one prime of the form $6x-1$ for the same reason as above.

Therefore, it follows that $y$ cannot be the highest prime of this form and we have proven that there are infinitely many.

Comment: This answer seems incorrect. Notably, you claim that 6x+1-6=6x+5, when in fact it is 6x-5. Would we be able to correct this proof by instead analyzing v-2?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that!  I fixed the typo.  Please let me know if you notice any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: there are infinite primes of the form $6k-1$,$k\in \mathbb{Z}$

**Proof**:
we will use the following two facts

- **Fact 1**: $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n$ is of the form $6k+i$ with $i\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$
- **Fact 2**: the set of integers of the form $6k+1$ is closed under multiplication

Now we start the proof.

Assume towards a contradiction that there are only finite primes of the form $6k+1$, label them $p_i, i\in\{1,2,..,r\}$.

Define the following integer, $n:=6(p_1p_2...p_r)-1$

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $n$ has at least one prime divisor. Choose arbitrarily a prime divisor of $n$, and call it $p$. Note that $n$ is odd, so given that $p|n$ we conclude $p$ is odd. This implies by **fact 1** that $p$ is of the form $6k+1$ or $6k-1$.

Note the following: $p$ cannot divide $p_1p_2...p_r$ for otherwise we would get that $p|1$ (to see this, rearrange $n$ and use some basic properties of divisibility). This fact implies that $p$ is a prime that was not on our list. Since $\forall p_i\in\{p_i, i=1,..,r\}, p_i=6k_i-1$ by assumption it must follow that $p=6k'+1$.

Recall that $p$ was an arbitrary prime factor of $n$, thus $n=\prod_i(6k_i+1)=6m+1$ (**fact 2**).

We thus get the following equalities:

$n=6m+1$

$n=6(p_1p_2...p_r)-1$

Subtracting the second equation from the first equation we get:

$6(p_1p_2...p_r-m)=2$ this implies that $6|2$ which is false, thus reaching a contradiction. Thus proving the claim.

Answer (score 0):

(i) $(6n-1)(6m-1) = \cdots = 6(\cdots) + 1$ (find this by expanding and factoring out a 6).

(ii) Fix $n = 6q+r > 3$ (a result of the division algorithm) where $q\ge0$ and $0 \le r < 6$. Examine the possibilities of $r$. Clearly, $0$, $2$, $3$, and $4$ can be eliminated (why?). What are the other possibilities and what do they imply about $n$?

Comment: your result for (i) appears wrong: $(6-1)(6-1)=(4\cdot 6 + 1)$, not $\cdots-1$

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Expand: (6j + 1)(6k + 1) = 36jk + 6j + 6k + 1 = 6(6jk + j + k) + 1
Let m = 6jk + j + k
= 6m + 1

To answer the second part, think about what a prime number means. By definition, no prime p > 3 may have 3 or 2 as a factor.

All integers can be written in the form 6q + a, where *a* is an integer between 0 and 5.
6n - 1 = 6q + 5  for  q = n + 1

6q + 0 = 6(q)
6q + 1 = 6q + 1
6q + 2 = 2(3q + 1)
6q + 3 = 3(2q + 1)
6q + 4 = 2(3q + 2)
6q + 5 = 6q + 5

As you can see, the only possible primes above are *6q + 1* and *6q + 5*, as they are the only ones that cannot be expressed as a product of two numbers.